# I want to convert a string containing letters to a double in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

```
East_Seed_1="MIA";
East_Seed_8="ATL";

for i=1:7
    s=rand;

    if s<MIA_prob_vs_ATL
        s=1;
```

I want to create an algorithm that, given probabilities of each team against another and the 8 seeds will determine a playoff winner. I have defined the variables containing the seeds with the conference and the probabilities with the tickers.Is there some way I can get the probability referring to the seeds?(As to write East_Seed_1_prob_vs_East_Seed_8 in this case)
Thanks guys, you're awesome

Comment: What should "XYZ" be in double?

Comment: I was thinking to get it to be the indices of the letter as A=1,B=2 or something

Comment: You need to think about what you want to accomplish before you ask people how to accomplish it. "or something" is not very precise. Please [edit] your post to include example inputs and outputs, as well as your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output to give the alphabetical order of the letters, 1 to 26, you can do this:

```
str = "ABCXYZ";
mat = char(str);
ds = double(mat) - 64
```

which gives

```
ds =  1     2     3    24    25    26
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'];
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

string = 'ABCADEM';
answer = [];

for i = 1 : length(letters)
   indeces = strfind(string,letters(i));
   for j = 1 : length(indeces)
       answer(indeces(j)) = numbers(i);
   end
end

doubleAnswer = str2double(sprintf('%1d',answer));
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.